# How to export to excel with specified month

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

```
Sub Initialize
    'Copyright Botstation (www.botstation.com)
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim wks As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim view As NotesView
    Dim uiView As NotesUIView
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim column As NotesViewColumn

    Dim row As Long,colcounter As Long,arrcnt As Long,arrcounter As Long, x As Long
    Dim filename As String, currentvalue As String
    Dim rowsatonce As Integer,cn As Integer
    Dim xlApp As Variant, xlsheet As Variant,xlwb As Variant, xlrange As Variant, tempval As Variant
    Dim DataArray
    Dim VColumns List As String

    ReDim DataArray(0, 80) As String
    '80 columns is our expected max number of columns in the view. It's dynamically recomputed below to actual (lower) number. Change if the number of columns is larger.

    Set db=session.CurrentDatabase
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    xlApp.Visible = True 'Excel program is visible (to avoid errors and see what is happening)

    Set xlwb=xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set xlsheet =xlwb.Worksheets(1)

    Set uiView = wks.CurrentView
    Set view = db.GetView( uiView.ViewName ) ' get the view currently open in UI
    arrcnt=0
    row=1
    colcounter=0
    rowsatonce=20
    ForAll c In view.Columns
        If c.isIcon<>True Then ' do not include icon columns
            If c.Formula<>"""1""" And c.Formula<>"1" Then 'do not include columns which are used for counting docs (Total)
                colcounter=colcounter+1
                DataArray(row-1, colcounter-1) =c.Title
                VColumns(CStr(cn))=CStr(cn)
            End If
        End If
        cn=cn+1
    End ForAll
    ReDim Preserve DataArray(0, colcounter-1) As String
    xlsheet.Range("A1").Resize(1, colcounter).Value = DataArray ' set column names
    ReDim DataArray(rowsatonce-1, colcounter-1) As String
    row=2
    x=0
    Set doc = view.GetFirstDocument
    While Not ( doc Is Nothing )
        ForAll col In VColumns
            currentvalue=""
            tempval= doc.ColumnValues(Val(col))
            If IsArray(tempval) Then
                ForAll v In tempval
                    If currentvalue="" Then
                        currentvalue=v
                    Else
                        currentvalue=currentvalue+","+v
                    End If
                End ForAll
            Else
                currentvalue=tempval
            End If
            x=x+1
            DataArray(arrcounter, x-1) =currentvalue
        End ForAll
        x=0
        row=row+1
        arrcounter=arrcounter+1
        If arrcounter/rowsatonce=arrcounter\rowsatonce And arrcounter<>0 Then
            xlsheet.Range("A"+Cstr(arrcnt*rowsatonce+2)).Resize(rowsatonce, colcounter).Value = DataArray
            arrcnt=arrcnt+1
            arrcounter=0
            ReDim DataArray(rowsatonce-1, colcounter-1) As String
        End If
        Set doc = view.GetNextDocument (doc)
    Wend

    If arrcounter/rowsatonce<>arrcounter\rowsatonce And arrcounter>0 Then
        ' Redim Preserve DataArray(arrcounter, colcounter-1) As String
        xlsheet.Range("A"+Cstr(arrcnt*rowsatonce+2)).Resize(arrcounter, colcounter).Value = DataArray
    End If
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit the code (using the {} code tag) so it is easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have got the month that you want to include you can add a condition after this line:

```
While Not ( doc Is Nothing )
```

Compare the month (and probably year) with the (date) item on the document. You might need the `NotesDateTime` class to do this.

To filter the right month you can do this: (assuming you also need the year)

```
If year(date1) * 100 + month(date1) = year(date2) * 100 + month(date3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,I found a solution using selection formula. But I'm having trouble on a column wherein I'm retrieving a date/time field. I want to compare my date/time field to a specific month but i can't seem to get any results. TIA

Comment: The view should only show documents with a specific date/month?

Comment: Hi, Currently I'm doing this formula in my Lotusscript
**Formula = {SELECT Form = "Form1" | Form = "Form2" & productOfficer = GetValue}** where my get value is holds a the value from the prompt list. But I can't seem to get any results. I would like to know if it's possible to pass a prompt list value to a formula? if there is would you please tell me the syntax. Thank you so much.

Comment: Updating the view selection formula in that way will not work. There are a few options, build the view in a way that it is easy to select the documents you need, or filter the (selected) documents on the fly. You can put an action in the view that will ask the user for the month. Then loop through the documents and filter them based on the input from the user.

Comment: Would you be so kind to help me out with the syntax?, I'm quite confused.